# ECHO command in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch programming, currently facing one issue in below batch script.

```
REM 

SET Var1=10
SET Var2=20

SET Var3 = john

SET Var4 = john1

ECHO variable values

ECHO %Var1%
ECHO %Var2%
ECHO %Var3%
ECHO %Var4%

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\\ " %%a in ("%1") do set component=%%a&set app=%%b

pause
EXIT
```

The issue is as stated below,

the statements `ECHO %Var3%`, `ECHO %Var4%` ==> won't produce the desired result which is to print the string value they are assigned to. Instead in prints ECHO ON.

Not sure what is the issue. I know it is trivial please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%var3%` not equal to `%Var3%`. So, your `%Var3%==" john"` and your `%var3%==""`. When you call `echo` with empty parameter, it prints current echo mode (on or off).

Also `SET Var3 = john` is not equal to `SET Var3=john`. First command means 'create variable "Var3 " (i.e. it's name consists of 5 characters - fifth is space) with value " john"' (it's values starts with space). Try to add following lines in your script to see it:

```
ECHO %Var3 %
ECHO %Var4 %
```

Comment: TO be specific the numerical values are ECHOed correctly but the issue is with string data

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, one question, what does SET Var3=john mean?. means how different from SET Var3 = john.

Comment: Also one more doubt, in statement,                                          for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\\ " %%a in ("%1") do set component=%%a&set app=%%b                                                                  what would be the value of app, if input to the batch is just the string,  hi .

Comment: I know that i would be equivalent to "SET app="  is it possible to check using IF statement if the value in "app""is a valid string or not?

Comment: What does 'valid string' mean?

Comment: Say in case input to the batch file is "hi\man", inn that case "app=man". but in case if the input is just "hi", then value of app would be equivalent to "SET app=", correct?. So, my question is is it possible to identify this scenario? Using IF statement.

Comment: 1) Yes, you can check is string empty: `if %app%.==. echo app string is empty`; 2) It is better to remove the most of your comments above, because now they are useless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good method to echo a blank line when the variable is empty, or otherwise echo the variable.

```
ECHO(%Var1%
```